# Noble Integers (Java)

Tags: java, sorting

Given an integer array A, find if an integer p exists in the array such that the number of integers greater than p in the array equals p.Return 1 if any such integer p is present else, return -1.

i tried this but this only passed some test cases..

```
public class Solution {
    public int solve(int[] A) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        int [] newarr = new int [A.length];
        for (int i = A.length -1 ; i >=0 ; i--){
            newarr[A.length-1-i]=A[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0 ; i < A.length ; i++){
            if (newarr[i]==i){
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort your array in descending order, the index of an element basically tell you there are n-element that is either larger or equals to that element.

e.g.

```
index:  0    1    2    3    4    5    6
value: 11    9    6    6    6    5    2
```

index 0, the value is 11 and there is 0 value that is larger/equals to 11.
index 5, the value is 5 and there is 5 value that are larger/equals to 5.

The tricky part are the duplicated values: index 2,3,4 are all 6, and only the first one (index 2) is telling you that 2 elements are greater than it.

So it is basically sorting the array in descending order, find any index that is the same as the value in array, and make sure that value is the first one in duplicated sequence:

```
sort array in desc order

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == i && (i == 0 || array[i-1] != array[i]) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false
```

Comment: Why didn't I think about reversing the sort order, that makes it so much simpler! Anyway, if you check that the first value is not zero before entering the loop, you can start from 1 and simplify the test inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the array first was a good idea. And since you are now working on a sorted array, you only need one loop. Pick a number from index `i` and if number of elements after `i` equals value in `i`, then return `1`. You also need to check if there are identical values in the array, since the rule was "number of integers *greater than* p in the array equals p". Remember that integers can also be negative or zero.

```
Arrays.sort(a);

// If the last value is zero we can stop immediately. This helps
// remove one array length check from the next loop.
if (a[a.length - 1] == 0) {
    return 1;
}

// Loop until next-to-last. The last element was checked
// above.
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    final int p = a[i];

    // Ignore value if the next one is not greater.
    if (p == a[i + 1]) {
        continue;
    }

    if (p == (a.length - i - 1)) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

For future reference, it would be helpful in debugging to add the failing test cases. But it didn't matter here because rewriting your algorithm was easier.

Answer (score 0):

- first, handle the special cases of empty or null array. Then check for the special case of `[0]` to avoid needless repetitive logic within the main loop.
- sort the array.
- then iterate across the array until you find a value that equals the number left to iterate while making certain that the numbers ahead of it are not equal to the found solution.

Note that it is not required to iterate across the entire array. If the the current value is greater than the amount of numbers remaining, then no solution can exist so the loop is terminated.

```
public static int solve(int[] arr) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (arr[arr.length-1] == 0) { 
        return 1;
    }
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (int i = 0; arr[i] < arr.length-i; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arr.length - i - 1 && arr[i] != arr[i+1]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```